# Counts in the while 0 to 10

Tags: php, mysql, sql, for-loop, while-loop

**My code has shown below**

```
$number_of_book=0;
$res_best_book=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book ORDER BY best DESC");
while($best_book=mysql_fetch_assoc($res_best_book)){
    echo "Number Of Book";$number_of_book++;
    echo "&nbsb;&nbsb;";
    print_r($best_book['book_name']);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

**And it is my actual output:**

```
Number Of Book   BOOK58   
Number Of Book   BOOK91
Number Of Book   BOOK532
Number Of Book   BOOK1
Number Of Book   BOOK21
Number Of Book   BOOK84
```

**Expected output would be**

```
Number Of Book 1  BOOK58
Number Of Book 2  BOOK91
Number Of Book 3  BOOK32
Number Of Book 4  BOOK1
Number Of Book 5  BOOK21
Number Of Book 6  BOOK84
```

Comment: Just echo your number after you increment it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$number_of_book=1;
$res_best_book=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book ORDER BY best DESC");
while($best_book=mysql_fetch_assoc($res_best_book)){
    echo "Number Of Book ".$number_of_book++." ".$best_book['book_name']." <br>";
    $number_of_book++;
}
```

Comment: Why add a new variable?

Comment: @Barmar I don't know what he is using this $number_of_book variable for. He wasn't using in his question, I just kept it as it was.

Comment: Isn't it just the book number that needs to be printed?

Comment: It doesn't look like, otherwise he would just print that and didn't need to question anything..

Comment: That's the point of his question, he didn't know how to print it!

Answer (score 0):

```
$number_of_book=1;
$res_best_book=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book ORDER BY best DESC");
while($best_book=mysql_fetch_assoc($res_best_book)){
    echo "Number Of Book".$number_of_book;
    echo "&nbsb;&nbsb;";
    print_r($best_book['book_name']);
    echo "<br>";
    $number_of_book++;
}
```

Comment: @GGO What does that mean? `$res_best_book` is a result object, not a number.